# I want to change phone_number whenever I change user in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

When I choose the select, it give me id from 'user' table. I want when I change the choose from User select, the value in  below is also change. This is my code:

```
<select name="User" class="selectinput" onchange="updatePhone()">
                        <option value selected>User</option>
                        <?php
                        $usersql = "SELECT id, name, phone FROM user";
                        $userresult = mysqli_query($conn, $usersql);
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($userresult) > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userresult)) {
                                echo "<option value='" . $row["id"] . "' data-phone='" . $row["phone"] . 
"'>" . $row["name"] . "</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>

                    <div class="w-100 d-flex">
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <div class="align-self-center">
                                Phone number:
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input style="width:80%" type="text" name="Phone" id="phone-input">
                    </div>
```

And this is my Script:

```
function updatePhone() {
    var phone = $('select[name="User"]').data('phone');
    $('#phone-input').value(phone);
  }
```

Comment: Print the user id - phone number pairs into a js array from php and use the onchange to read the phone number from the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To archive that u can modify the function as follows

function update_Phone() {
    let select_element = document.querySelector(".selectinput"); // getting select element
    let phone_input = document.getElementById("phone-input"); // get the input to to which you will assing new value
    let selected_option = select_element.options[select_element.selectedIndex]; // get the selected option 
    let phone = selected_option.getAttribute("data-phone"); // get the value assing to the attributes of the selected option`enter code here`

    phone_input.value = phone; // assing value to the input on select
}
```